# Clear Home Launcher default value

Tags: android, android-launcher

I've read a lot of question about how to set a launcher application as the default one.

I want to accomplish the opposite, assuming I have a launcher application, and that it has been set to default by the user, is there a way to clear my application from been the default one, without uninstalling the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `public abstract void clearPackagePreferredActivities` from `PackageManager`

use:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("your.package.name");
```

You can only clear the packages assigned to your application.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yeah, I've found this shortly after posting the question... Thanks for the hassle ;)